# How to retrieve a PKDrawing from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to implement notes feature in my app and the way I've implemented saving `PKDrawings` is below:

```
 func saveDrawingData() {
        var drawingDataArray = [String : Any]()
        let drawingData = convertImageToBase64String(img: canvasView.screenshot!)
        
        drawingDataArray["drawing_data"] = drawingData
        
        if let client = selectedClient, let fileNumber = selectedFileNumber {
            dbm.addCaseDataToDatabase(client, fileNumber, drawingDataArray)
        } else {
            print("Data not sent to Firestore")
        }
    }
```

I do that by converting the drawing to an image using the "screenshot" method below:

```
extension UIView {
    var screenshot : UIImage? {
    var screenshot :UIImage?
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
    layer.render(in:context)
    screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return screenshot
    }
}
```

While the data successfully saves to Firestore, I'm now trying to retrieve that `PKDrawing` from the database and put it back on the canvas so it can be further edited and saved.

Below is my code for displaying the data that has been downloaded from the database:

```
    func displayDrawingFromDatabase(from data: [String: Any]) -> UIView {
        if let drawing = data["drawing_data"] {
            //convert downloaded key-value pair to image
            let downloadedImage = convertBase64StringToImage(imageBase64String: drawing as! String)
            //convert image to string
            let imageString = convertImageToBase64String(img: downloadedImage)
            //convert string to data
            let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
            //Apply to canvasView
            canvasView.drawing = imageData
        }
        return canvasView
    }
```

When I do so, I get the error:

```
cannot assign value of type Data? to type PKDrawing
```

I've attempted to extract the data from the drawing using the `.dataRepresentation()` method, but I was unable to successfully extract the data from the key-value pair in `displayDrawingDataFromDatabase()`.
What should I do to fix the code?

EDIT:

I call `displayDrawingFromDatabase()` using:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

       if let client = selectedClient, let fileNumber = selectedFileNumber {
           dbm.readDrawingDataFromDatabase(client, fileNumber) { (caseData, success) in
               self.displayDrawingFromDatabase(from: caseData)
       }
    }
```

and that code is based upon the function below:

```
   func readDrawingDataFromDatabase(_ client: Client, _ fileNumber: FileNumber, completion: @escaping ((_ documentData: [String: Any], _ success: Bool) -> Void)) {
        guard let uid: String = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return print("Cannot retrieve uid")}

        let clientDocumentID = client.documentID
        let fileNumberDocumentID = fileNumber.documentID
        
        let clientRef = db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("clients")
        let fileNumberRef = clientRef.document(clientDocumentID).collection("file_numbers")
        
        let query = fileNumberRef.whereField("document_id", isEqualTo: fileNumberDocumentID as Any)
        
        query.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    let documentData: [String: Any] = document.data()
                    completion(documentData, true)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns in the question so it's going to be impossible to answer as is. Why are you not saving the strokes that make up the drawing instead of a screen shot? What are you passing in to `displayDrawingFromDatabase`? And why are you returning `return canvasView` when it appears to be a class var? What specific line is throwing the error? Have you added a breakpoint and stepped through the code line by line, examining the vars to determine which one is going wrong? Please update and clarify the question & code and we'll take a look.

Comment: First, thanks for looking at it. As for your questions: 1. Why are you

Comment: To answer your questions: 1. Why are you not saving the strokes? I have no idea how to do that. I just happened to find the screenshot method and it seemed to work. 2. I call displayingDrawingFromDatabase using `if let client = selectedClient, let fileNumber = selectedFileNumber {
            dbm.readDrawingDataFromDatabase(client, fileNumber) { (caseData, success) in
                self.displayDrawingFromDatabase(from: caseData)
        }` 3. The line that throws the error is: `canvasView.drawing = imageData`. The error is `cannot assign value of type Data to type PKDrawing`.

Comment: Please don't add code in comments - its very hard to read. Update your *question* with further details. The code is confusing - `displayDrawingFromDatabase` returns a UIView so it's unclear why canvasView is a PKDrawing. Additionally, if you're storing images, there''s no reason to Encode/Decode them - they can be directly stored in [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage). Firestore is not a good place to store blobs in general. Also, if canvasView is in fact a PK Drawing, you can't assign data to it `let imageData = Data(` so that bit of code doesn't make sense.

Comment: I apologize. I've updated the code above. My initial goal was to store `PKDrawing`s, but my understanding based upon other SO posts I've reviewed is that Firestore doesn't allow for saving them directly and that they must first be converted to a Base64 string and then decoded back into a drawing (the last conversion was the one I was having issues with). How would you recommend I implement saving drawings?

Comment: If you want to save an actual drawing (UIImage) or a .pdf or a .numbers spreadsheet or really any kind of file, refer to the link in my comment to store them in Firebase Storage as that's what it's for. Firestore fields are not the right place to store large files (blobs). Keep in mind that PKDrawings are composed of an array of individual PKStrokes - that's what I would store in Firestore. You'll still need to to encode/decode them as NSData but that's far more flexible than storing the document as a file as you then have access to each stroke.

Comment: I would also suggesting using NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver to store and retrieve data from Firestore (e.g. Any, or String or PKStroke etc).